# Hide window in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, window, hide

I have an MFC C++ app, I need my app to run in background, to do run some functions.
So I want to disable the dialog window .In other words I am trying to hide/make it invisible to the user.

How could I do this ? I don't have much experience with MFC, I would really appreciate the help.

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the mainframe using `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`.

Refer [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).